# Does matlab treat colon mark differently during variable assignment and indexing without assignment?

Tags: matlab

For example I have a 1*30 structure a.field, when I type a(:).field in command window it just iteratively display a(1).field, a(2).field,... However, when I was trying to assign a(:).field to another variable b, what b get is just a(1).field.

BTW, if I attampt to pass a(:).field to a function, Matlab just throws an error "too many input arguments".

What is the mechanism behind? My guess is that matlab threat colon equivlant to the first element during assignment, is that true?

Comment: The colon operator is simply "all" in this case. `a(:)` means *all elements in `a`*. So, if you use `a(:).field`, you are passing *all* elements of your struct `a` which have a first level name `field`. That's apparently more than your function can take.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets, otherwise matlab don't understand that your trying to store an array:

```
b = [a(:).field]
```

Another option that provide similar result:

```
b = horzcat(a(:).field)
```

Comment: Thanks. So I have to use a bracket to tell matlab that the variable I am going to create is not a number but an array. However, if a(1).field itself is a vector, then the assigned variable 'b' will actually be a vector(array), in this case, b=[a(:).field] turns out to be a 1*60 vector. How can I get a 30*2 martix by a single line assignment?

Comment: b=vertcat(a(:).field) makes it. Thanks so much.